# Visual Studio error in SFML: <Information not available, no symbols loaded for sfml-audio-d-2.dll>

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

When I run the code, everything works except that the sound does not play. The link is fine, when I put a breakpoint and look at the sound object, it displays . I have added sfml-audio-d.lib and sfml-audio.lib in the right places. Any suggestions welcome.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "SFML/Audio.hpp"
int main() {

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "SFML Application");

sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
buffer.loadFromFile("magicsound.mp3");

sf::Sound sound;

sound.setBuffer(buffer);
sound.play();

//
sf::Sprite background;

sf::Texture texture;

texture.loadFromFile("crash.jpg");

background.setTexture(texture);

while (window.isOpen()) {

    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {

        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
        {
            sf::FloatRect visibleAre(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
            window.setView(sf::View(visibleAre)); //background stays default size
            //window can be resized without affecting background
        }
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(background);
    window.display();
}
```

}

Comment: start by checking the return value of loadFromFile.

Comment: is there a message from console window when you run the program?

Answer (score 1):

When you use quotes for including, ide looks for the library in your project's directory. If your project directory have own sfml library in itself I dont know; but it is like a typo to me.

So try this:

```
"SFML/Audio.hpp" --> <SFML/Audio.hpp>
```

and result is:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
```